# How to get consistent spacing from the body to the footer in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, footers, line-spacing

I am writing here to see if anyone can help me out with a spacing issue at the bottom of pages in Microsoft Word.

It appears that the spacing between the body and the footer changes on different pages. For example, sometimes Word allows an extra line of the body paragraph to fit onto the page while in other instances it simply pushes it onto the next page, thus making the spacing inconsistent across pages.

Is there any way to systematically make the spacing uniform by setting limits in the settings?

I've attached a few screenshots that demonstrate this inconsistency in spacing across pages to help show what I'm talking about.

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1):

Good practical question, & the attachments are helpful: The page following the  first attachment may be of significance, since the program may be avoiding an orphaned word, line of a paragraph, chapter heading, etc. In the second example, the font/ point size appears to differ for the ending line. If so, adjustment of the setting(s) for vertical spacing there may be required to compensate for the difference in vertical spacing compared with the other pages; or, insertion of additional blank lines, perhaps of the different font etc, to result in the intended vertical spacing, since he basis vertical spacing is affected by the font size at the place in the document. The program may try and keep footnotes together with their notations, which can result in some spacing inconsistencies. Also, the spacing in final printout(if done) may vary from the screen preview/ depending on the equipment etc.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part it is these two settings—Bottom on the Margins tab and Footer on the Layout tab—that together define the distance between the body text and the footer text. You can reduce the distance between the text and the footer by decreasing the Bottom setting and/or increasing the Footer setting.

To got to the settings it`s founf in Page Setup > Layout > Margins & layout Tabs. You can change the margin values (Usually given in inches)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to systematically make the spacing uniform by setting limits in the settings?

Word controls spacing through several settings from font through paragraph to margin settings.
Empty space at the bottom of the page is the result of those and not a setting, so it's very difficult to precisely control it.

In your **first screenshot** last page has one line less, next page is not visible so it's not possible to tell you the reason for sure, I'd guess it's there to avoid having an [orphan line](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/control-pagination-e9b3b005-cf62-41d0-afa2-24cfb223ab42)

On the **second screenshot** first & second pages have shorter text, both could've accommodated a couple of more lines.
However the lines moved to the next page both cases had footnotes in them, moving the lines to previous page would've meant the need to move footnotes too, however there is not enough place for that.